# Error adding new item

Tags: php, xml

All good day. When using crxml repository, not correctly generated xml document. And that's what happens when you add a new element into the document. Course of action:
To begin with I create document

```
        $this->genXml->Item['Type'] = 'view';
        $this->genXml->Item->{'http://'.$this->siteUrll.'|Name'}    = 'Last View';

        $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View->Time = $app['Time'];
        $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View->Action = $app['Action'];
        $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View->IP = $app['IP'];
        return $this->genXml->xml();
```

and I get this kind of xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item Type="view">
  <Name xmlns="http://sitename.com">Last View</Name>
  <LastView>
    <View>
      <Time>11:45:12</Time>
      <Action>Click</Action>
      <IP>192.168.1.1</IP>
    </View>
  </LastView>
</Item>
```

further to the finished result add new values

```
            $GetFile = <<<EOB
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <Item Type="view">
              <Name xmlns="http://sitename.com">Last View</Name>
              <LastView>
                <View>
                  <Time>11:45:12</Time>
                  <Action>Click</Action>
                  <IP>192.168.1.1</IP>
                </View>
              </LastView>
            </Item>
        EOB;
            $this->genXml->loadXML($GetFile);
            $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View[2]->Time = $app['Time'];
            $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View[2]->Action = $app['Action'];
            $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View[2]->IP = $app['IP'];

            echo($this->genXml->xml());
```

and get the faulty code xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item Type="view">
      <Name xmlns="http://sitename.com">Last View</Name>
      <LastView>
        <View>
          <Time>11:45:12</Time>
          <Action>Click</Action>
          <IP>192.168.1.1</IP>
        </View>
      <View/><View><Time>11:45:12</Time><Action>Click</Action>   <IP>192.168.1.1</IP></View></LastView>
    </Item>
```

namely where the tag is

```
<View/>
```

Help solve a problem with the output. Maybe I am doing something wrong? (sorry for my English, I know im not as good as I would like)
Just give the link to the [repository](https://github.com/sandeepcr529/crxml) and a [description](https://github.com/sandeepcr529/crxml/issues/1) of the problem.

Comment: Who is downvoting this question?

Comment: Offsets start at 0, not at 1; so you should be adding `$this->genXml->Item->LastView->View[1]->Time`, etc

Comment: This is just an example of the code. General count is so:    foreach($this->genXml->Item->LastView as $key=>$value)
    {
     $i[] = $key;
    }
    $next_i = count($i) + 1;
    $this->genXml->Item->LastView->View[$next_i]->Time = $app['Time'];

Comment: @vitaly63 - the principle still applies, offsets start at 0, so to add a new element at the end you use an offset of count, not count+1

Comment: I would downvote this question if it wasn't a question that is very common. Instead I still upvote it so more people might find this in a google search.

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for such a quick reply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somehow hilarious as it is a typical problem of Informatics. We like to start counting from 0. You created a first view with the ID 0 (implicit). If you now add a new view with the ID 2, it misses the ID 1 and simply inserts an empty view. The result is thereby syntactically correct.

You just have to change the index of the added view to 1 to prevent this.

Comment: Thank you so much. Was all so elementary. I too started to sin at the library itself. Thank you all for the help.